# Handling null inside .map in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, null

I want to map over an ImageCollection and calculate percentiles of a region. Some images are empty for my area of interest, due to cloud masking.

How do I handle something like:

```
if variable ==null :
  continue with next image
```

I prepared some code with the exact problem:

[GEE code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/11215e462dbf019d2ac30ed83f4579db)

Can the following normalize function be altered to incorporate the occasional `null` value?

```
var normalize = function(Im){
  var time = Im.get("system:time_start")
  var percentiles = Im.reduceRegion({
    reducer:ee.Reducer.percentile([10,90],["10","90"]),
    crs:proj.crs,
    crsTransform:proj.transform,
    maxPixels:1000000000
  })
  var p10 = ee.Number(percentiles.get("band_10"))
  print(p10,"p10")
  var p90 = ee.Number(percentiles.get("band_90"))
  print(p90,"p90")
  return Im.subtract(p10).divide(p90.subtract(p10)).set({"system:time_start":time})
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not a great way to skip an image in the `map` function. However, you can use the [`ee.Algorithms.If`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-algorithms-if) function to control what happens when null is encountered. In your case, if all pixels in the region are masked, the reducer will return `null`. Instead of trying to do math operations with `null`, you can return a masked image (no attempt to normalize). Additionally, set an 'isNull' property so that you can filter on it once the normalize function has been mapped over the collection. Here is `ee.Algorithms.If` implemented in your snippet:

```js
var normalize = function(Im){
  var time = Im.get("system:time_start");
  var percentiles = Im.reduceRegion({
    reducer:ee.Reducer.percentile([10,90],["10","90"]),
    crs:proj.crs,
    crsTransform:proj.transform,
    maxPixels:1000000000
  });
  
  var p10 = ee.Number(percentiles.get("band_10"));
  print(p10,"p10");
  var p90 = ee.Number(percentiles.get("band_90"));
  print(p90,"p90");
  
  var outImg = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(
    p10, 
    Im.subtract(p10).divide(p90.subtract(p10)).set('isNull', false),
    ee.Image(0).selfMask().set('isNull', true)
  ));
  
  return outImg.set({"system:time_start":time});
};
```

If you wanted to filter the null images out of the collection do this:

```js
var normCol = imgCol
  .select(["B1"], ["band"])
  .map(normalize);
  
var normColNotNull = normCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq('isNull', false));
```

Note that `ee.Algorithms.If` should be used with caution because it will always evaluate both the true and false alternatives, which takes extra time and resources.

Comment: This is such a frustrating limitation of GEE, there's no streamlined way to handle null values and exceptions so it's very hard to automate some tasks.