# Skipping an image in .map() function in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to compute the monthly Vegetation Condition Index (VCI): VCI = (NDVI_mean-NDVI_min) /(NDVI_max-NDVI_min). This is my code:

```
var VCI_sow = years.map(function(year) {
  return sowMonths.map(function (month) {
    var filtered = monthly_sowing_Avg.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', year))
                                    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
    var NDVI_M_Y = ee.Image(filtered.first())
    var minNDVI_M_Y = ee.Image(monthly_sowing_Min.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
                                                .first())
    var maxNDVI_M_Y = ee.Image(monthly_sowing_Max.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
                                                .first())
                            
    var image = ee.Image.cat([NDVI_M_Y, minNDVI_M_Y, maxNDVI_M_Y])
                        .rename(['NDVI', 'min', 'max'])
    // VCI = (NDVI - min) / (max - min)
    return image.expression('100* (NDVI - min) / (max - min)',
    {'NDVI': image.select('NDVI'),
    'min': image.select('min'),
    'max': image.select('max')
      
    }).rename('VCI')
      .set({'month': month, 'year': year});
  });
}).flatten();
```

for some reason the line

```
   var image = ee.Image.cat([NDVI_M_Y, minNDVI_M_Y, maxNDVI_M_Y])
                       .rename(['NDVI', 'min', 'max'])
```

raises an error. I tried to go year by year and month by month. Apparently not having images on certain dates is the problem. Is there a way to skip those dates?

Comment: Could you provide a link to your code?

Comment: @MadeleineNicolas I added the link.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: List (Error) Image.addBands: Parameter 'dstImg' is required

Comment: The link you added does not provide access to your code, you need to use the "Get Link" feature to get a shareable link !

Comment: I updated the Link @MadeleineNicolas

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it based on the solution provided [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341685/handling-null-inside-map-in-google-earth-engine?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
var VCI_sow = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(years.map(function(year) {
  return sowMonths.map(function (month) {
    var filtered = monthly_sowing_Avg.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', year))
                                     .filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
    var NDVI_M_Y = ee.Image(filtered.first())
    var minNDVI_M_Y = ee.Image(monthly_sowing_Min.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
                                                .first())
    var maxNDVI_M_Y = ee.Image(monthly_sowing_Max.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
                                                .first())
                            
    
//There is not a great way to skip an image in the map function. 
//The ee.Algorithms.If function can control what happens when null is encountered. 
//Instead of trying to do math operations (to compute VCI) with null, we can return a masked
//image (no attempt to compute VCI). Additionally, we can set an 'isNull' property so that we can 
//filter on it once the VCI is calculated for all the collection.
  
    var image = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(
      NDVI_M_Y,
      // VCI = (NDVI - min) / (max - min)
      (NDVI_M_Y.subtract(minNDVI_M_Y).divide(maxNDVI_M_Y.subtract(minNDVI_M_Y))).multiply(100)
      .set('isNull', false), ee.Image(0).selfMask().set('isNull', true)
                               
  ));
    return image.rename('VCI')
                .set({'month': month, 'year': year});
  });
}).flatten());
```